# Qt: gstreamer custom pipeline creation failure

Tags: qt, arm, gstreamer

I'm trying to create a custom pipeline with QtGStreamer. I modified [this](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/qt-gstreamer/tree/examples/player) example which uses "playbin2" to create the pipeline.

```
QGst::ElementPtr e1;
QGst::ElementPtr e2;

e1 = QGst::ElementFactory::make("videotestsrc");
e2 = QGst::ElementFactory::make("mfw_v4lsink");

m_pipeline = QGst::Pipeline::create();
m_pipeline->add(e1, e2);

this->setVideoSink(e2);
m_pipeline->setState(QGst::StatePlaying);
```

But I am experiencing the following errors:

```
QGst::Ui::VideoWidget: Could not construct a renderer for the specified element
"Internal data flow error."
```

Does anyone haave any experience with this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.